# Escape key strangely captured by javascript webshell

Tags: windows-7, firefox, ssh, vim, javascript

I am using [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) as a WebShell on my VPS (only way to SSH to it through the proxy of the place...), it uses javascript to emulate a shell by capturing keystrokes.

Everything works well, yet it seems the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is special : it often is understood wrongly by the server.

Mainly when I use VIM and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit edit mode, it does something else. Sometime it's simply a backspace, sometimes it deletes the line, sometimes it inserts a copy of a part of the current line at the cursor position...

Yet, clicking again in the Firefox window (while it already had the focus) restores the expected behavior.

So there are two questions here :

- The WebShell even performs to capture Firefox shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (new tab), so why is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key so special ?
- Is there a way for me to get rid of this problem ? By correcting this capture problem, or even, as it's only a problem with VIM, an other way than <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit edit mode ?

I'm stuck to using Firefox, it seems that IE and Chrome does not handle WebSockets correctly enough to have my webshell working through the proxy server (and so I couldn't test this <kbd>Esc</kbd> with them).

Even if there is no solution to my problem, I'm quite interested by an explanation of this behavior.

Comment: As a workaround, try Ctrl-C or Ctrl-[.